# Как можно сделать связь сущностей SQL как указвно на рисунке?

Tags: sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Как сделать то, что выделено красным?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут не все такие эстеты понимать подобные рисунки, так что опишите лучше словами, какие у вас есть сущности, какие связи вы хотите реализовать между ними, и в чем заключается ваша проблема.

Comment: обычные FK по виду один-к-одному. Контроль привязки к правильному типу только на уровне триггеров и приложения